HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive Function
hey every one so i'm trying to understand HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive behavior. i created a program which send 1 byte every 12s
master while loop
  Request = 0x5a;
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)&Request , (uint8_t *)&Responce, 1, 200);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  HAL_Delay(12000);

  Request = 0x52;
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)&Request , (uint8_t *)&Responce, 1, 200);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  HAL_Delay(12000);

   Request = 0x54;
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
 HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)&Request , (uint8_t *)&Responce, 1, 200);
   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_SET);
   HAL_Delay(12000);

master SPI Config :
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_256;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

at reciever side i enabled SPI interrupt by below codes:
NVIC->ISER[1] |= ( 1u<<3 );     //SPI1 Enable
SPI1->CR2 |= SPI_CR2_RXNEIE;    //SPI_ENABLE
SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;       //SPI_ENABLE
//NVIC_EnableIRQ(SPI1_IRQn);        //u can this to enable spi interrupt

and at interrupt routine i answer the requests :
SPI_RX_data[SPI_RX_Counter++] = SPI1 -> DR;
for(uint8_t i =0 ; i<10 ;i++)
{
    if(SPI_RX_data[i]==0x5a)
    {    
        SPI1->DR = 0x58;
    }
}

slave SPI config :
void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 1 */
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_SLAVE;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
  hspi1.Init.CRCLength = SPI_CRC_LENGTH_DATASIZE;
  hspi1.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 2 */

}

as you can see in logic analyzer
if i get a proper request(0x5A) the answer would send with the next request(0X52)
(i get 0x5a at second request but the answer (0x50) is in third request)
does any one know why this is happening ?
rx buffer on slave side:
RX_BUFFER
Logic Analyzer

Please, re-phrase the entire last passage. It's impossible to understand what you're saying and what exactly the problem is. Also, your logic analyzer picture has no useful information, maybe you included the wrong picture. Also, specify on what device RX Buffer from the image is located. Is it on master or on slave?

As soon as the first clock cycle for the first byte is generated by the master, it will be clocking in the data from the slave on the MISO pin. In your code, you don't have a byte queued up. Try sending (and receiving) two bytes at a time from the master. You'll receive nothing as the first byte is transmitted, but should receive the slave data as the second byte.

@pmacfarlane as i understand from what you said is i dont have any code to capture the data at transmitter side ... but i'm using HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive command which send the data and capture is's answer at the same time ...
can u explain more ?

@shayanghezelbash Your master is transmitting one byte. There will be 8 clock cycles as this byte is sent. At that point, you get an interrupt on the slave, which has received one byte. But the transaction is now over. The master clocked 8 bits of nothing into its receive buffer. Now you queue up a response on the slave, but it won't be seen on the master until it starts driving the clock again (12 seconds later). The transmit and receive happen literally at the same time.

well i want to work with SPI in full duplex mode so the transmit and receive should happen at the same time

SPI is full duplex. You'll need to queue up your response before the master transmits. Or, failing that, have the master send 2 bytes, and your response comes in the second received byte.
